# Insert a key value pair in a Tree map at a particular index

Tags: java, collections

I need to put elements in a Map and I chose the TreeMap implementation, the keys are to be placed in ascending sorted order in the map, but one of the keys which is "unassigned" should always be the first. Is this possible ?
My current code only puts the the elements in a sorted order ?

```
public class TreeMapTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //the treemap sorts by key
        Map<String, String> hm = new TreeMap<String, String>(new StringComparator());
        //add key-value pair to TreeMap
        hm.put("carrot","12");
        hm.put("apple", "34");
        hm.put("domboi","912");
        hm.put("unassigned","?");
        hm.put("banana", "45");  
        hm.put("zucchini","87");
        System.out.println("TreeMap Entries:");
        System.out.println(hm);

    }
}

class StringComparator implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }

}
```

The current output is

```
{apple=34, banana=45, carrot=12, domboi=912, unassigned=?, zucchini=87}
```

I want the output as

```
{unassigned=?,apple=34, banana=45, carrot=12, domboi=912,zucchini=87}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change your `Comparator` for this:

```
class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        if (str1.equals(str2)) {
            return 0;
        } else if ("unassigned".equals(str1)) {
            return -1;
        } else if ("unassigned".equals(str2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
TreeMap Entries:
{unassigned=?, apple=34, banana=45, carrot=12, domboi=912, zucchini=87}
```

Comment: It works, such a simple solution, currently solving the problem, thanks !
But what if I want to place my key at exactly say the 3rd position in the map or something like that ?

Comment: @Praneeth then you're out of luck.  There's no way to do that, really.

Comment: Although actually, @NicolasFilotto, your `Comparator` implementation will be badly broken.  `map.get("unassigned")` will _always_ return `null`.  You _must_ return `0` if the arguments are equal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Check out [my amazing `SillyMap`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37469001/3474) that allows putting a map entry at a specified position!

Comment: @LouisWasserman , Yes you are correct, there was a bug in the original code written by Nicolas as you said the get("unassigned") was not working properly and that was causing it to insert multiple keys with the same name "unassigned", I was surprised how that happened and now it is fixed. Thanks guys.

On a side note str1.compareTo(str2) would anyway check for the equal case and return 0 right ? why add another if condition to return 0( I know that solved the problem )

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* inject an element at a certain position. So, for example, the special entry can appear third in the iteration.

Just for fun, I came up with the following abomination. Rather than tinkering with the order, I wrapped a `TreeMap` together with an extra pseudo-entry. I'm not overly confident about how it will handle entry removal during iteration, but hopefully you get the idea.

I should point out that this map will always have an "unassigned" entry, with a default value of `null`. If you don't want that, you could use a similar approach, but wait to switch the `entries` member from a `TreeSet` to a `SillySet` when the "unassigned" key is added. Or something like that.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

final class SillyMap<K, V>
  extends AbstractMap<K, V>
{

  private final SillySet entries;

  SillyMap(K key, int unassigned)
  {
    entries = new SillySet(key, unassigned);
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()
  {
    return entries;
  }

  @Override
  public V put(K key, V value)
  {
    if (entries.extra.getKey().equals(key))
      return entries.extra.setValue(value);
    else
      return entries.map.put(key, value);
  }

  private final class SillySet
    extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>
  {

    final Map<K, V> map = new TreeMap<>();

    final Map.Entry<K, V> extra;

    private final int unassigned;

    SillySet(K key, int unassigned)
    {
      extra = new SimpleEntry<>(Objects.requireNonNull(key), null);
      if (unassigned < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      this.unassigned = unassigned;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator()
    {
      return new Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
      {

        private final Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();

        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
          return index < size();
        }

        @Override
        public Map.Entry<K, V> next()
        {
          Map.Entry<K, V> e;
          if (index == Math.min(unassigned, map.size()))
            e = extra;
          else
            e = i.next();
          ++index;
          return e;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove()
        {
          if (index - 1 == unassigned)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          i.remove();
          --index;
        }

      };
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
      return map.size() + 1;
    }

  };

  public static void main(String... argv)
  {
    final String KEY = "unassigned";
    Map<String, String> hm = new SillyMap<>(KEY, 3);
    hm.put("carrot", "12");
    hm.put("apple", "34");
    hm.put("domboi", "912");
    hm.put(KEY, "?");
    hm.put("banana", "45");
    hm.put("zucchini", "87");
    System.out.println(hm);
  }

}
```